# Downloading a file uploaded to a specific folder using a static URL given on another portlet gives "File not found" error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created a custom portlet for fileupload to upload files of type (.pdf, .doc, .txt, .docx).

After that I created another portlet in which I give a static URL to for these files for download, but it says `file not found`.

If I restart sever. files are downloaded and in local server it works fine without restart but on live server I need to restart server and only then the files are downloaded.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/CompanySidePortlet-portlet/gulfdiceResumes/<%=jobpost.getResume()%>" method="post">
    <button style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: lightblue; WIDTH: 25%; HEIGHT: 26px">Download</button>
</form>
```

this is form for download.. I have given URL against `localhost` on live site.

Environment: Liferay 6.1 with Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Tomcat uses some kind of CHMOD when the remote server is started, you could try with
`File tempFile= File.createTempFile("tempTest", ".pdf");`
and see what it gives you

also, is that path really correct?